# notaion of joint distribution of mixed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have some random variables $\mathbf{X}_1,...,\mathbf{X}_N$, where $N$ is a discrete random variable and $\mathbf{X}_i$ are i.i.d coutinuous random variable. What notation should I use for the joint distribution of such random vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pair of values $(n, x_{1:n})$. Here $x_{1:n}$ is the vector $(x_1, \dots, x_n$). You may write the density as
$$p(n, x_{1:n}) = P(N = n) f(x_{1:n} \mid N = n).$$
If the sample space of $X_i$ is $\mathbb{X}$ then for a given $n$, the pair $(n, x_{1:n})$ lies in $$\mathbb{Y}_n = \{n\} \times \mathbb{X}^n.$$ If the sample space for $n$ is $\mathbb{N}$ then the sample space for $(N, X_{1:N})$ is
$$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Y}_n.$$
I've taken the suggestions for the notation from [(Green, 1995)](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Escs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/TransdimMCMC/GreenRevJump.1995.pdf).

**References**

Green, Peter J., *Reversible Jump Markov Chain Monte Carlo Computation and Bayesian Model Determination*, Biometrika, Vol. 82, No. 4. (Dec., 1995), pp. 711-732

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more question, what I should call $p(1,x_{1:n})$? not a PDF, not a PMF. Can it be called as a distribution?

Comment: @Leon I agree, it's a mixture of a PMF and PDF. Peter Green uses the term 'distribution' in his paper so that would be a suitable name for $p(n, x_{1:n})$